Exoplayer: https://go_fm.streampartner.nl/live?type=.mp3 url not playing
Does anyone know what this error of Exoplayer is trying to play: https://go_fm.streampartner.nl/live?type=.mp3:
2024-04-16 17:16:03.298  8130-8228  LoadTask                com.familiekoning.radionedplus       E  Unexpected exception loading stream
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid input to toASCII: go_fm.streampartner.nl
at java.net.IDN.toASCII(IDN.java:115)
at javax.net.ssl.SNIHostName.(SNIHostName.java:99)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.getSSLParameters(Platform.java:192)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.getSSLParameters(ConscryptEngine.java:525)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.getSSLParameters(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:186)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.configureTlsExtensions(Platform.java:121)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:191)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:153)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:116)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:186)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:90)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
at androidx.media3.datasource.DefaultHttpDataSource.makeConnection(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:678)
at androidx.media3.datasource.DefaultHttpDataSource.makeConnection(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:575)
at androidx.media3.datasource.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:399)
at androidx.media3.datasource.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:275)
at androidx.media3.datasource.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:86)
at androidx.media3.exoplayer.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1029)
at androidx.media3.exoplayer.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:421)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
Caused by: The input does not conform to the STD 3 ASCII rules. line:  0. preContext:  . postContext: o_fm
at android.icu.impl.IDNA2003.convertToASCII(IDNA2003.java:218)
at android.icu.impl.IDNA2003.convertIDNToASCII(IDNA2003.java:276)
at android.icu.text.IDNA.convertIDNToASCII(IDNA.java:654)
at com.android.icu.text.ExtendedIDNA.convertIDNToASCII(ExtendedIDNA.java:50)
at java.net.IDN.toASCII(IDN.java:108)
... 27 more
2024-04-16 17:16:03.322  8130-8168  ExoPlayerImplInternal   com.familiekoning.radionedplus       E  Playback error
androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleIoException(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:717)
at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:693)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
Caused by: androidx.media3.exoplayer.upstream.Loader$UnexpectedLoaderException: Unexpected IllegalArgumentException: Invalid input to toASCII: go_fm.streampartner.nl
at androidx.media3.exoplayer.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:442)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid input to toASCII: go_fm.streampartner.nl
at java.net.IDN.toASCII(IDN.java:115)
at javax.net.ssl.SNIHostName.(SNIHostName.java:99)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.getSSLParameters(Platform.java:192)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.getSSLParameters(ConscryptEngine.java:525)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.getSSLParameters(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:186)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.configureTlsExtensions(Platform.java:121)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:191)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:153)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:116)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:186)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:90)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
at androidx.media3.datasource.DefaultHttpDataSource.makeConnection(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:678)
at androidx.media3.datasource.DefaultHttpDataSource.makeConnection(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:575)
at androidx.media3.datasource.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:399)
at androidx.media3.datasource.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:275)
at androidx.media3.datasource.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:86)
at androidx.media3.exoplayer.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1029)
at androidx.media3.exoplayer.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:421)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012) 
Caused by: The input does not conform to the STD 3 ASCII rules. line:  0. preContext:  . postContext: o_fm
                                                                                                      at android.icu.impl.IDNA2003.convertToASCII(IDNA2003.java:218)
                                                                                                      at android.icu.impl.IDNA2003.convertIDNToASCII(IDNA2003.java:276)
                                                                                                      at android.icu.text.IDNA.convertIDNToASCII(IDNA.java:654)
                                                                                                      at com.android.icu.text.ExtendedIDNA.convertIDNToASCII(ExtendedIDNA.java:50)
                                                                                                      at java.net.IDN.toASCII(IDN.java:108)


This SO post and this GitHub issue answers the question, it is due to the URL containing an underscore character which the toAscii() method cannot handle.
Thanks!
